# Element overflowing even with overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this list of songs, i'm using bootstrap and react, i'm trying to make the entirety of the elements fit inside the body, so that the "default" browser scroll bar does not appear, instead, i want my list-group to have the scroll bar, here is what i have right now:

[image]

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="App">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Songs</h1>
            <div class="mb-3 input-group">
                <input placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 1</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 2</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 3</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 4</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 5</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 6</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 7</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 8</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 9</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 10</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 11</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 12</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 13</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 14</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 15</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 16</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 17</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 18</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 19</div>
                <div class="list-group-item">Song 20</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#root{
  max-height: 100%;
}

.App {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

as you can see, i have put a max-height of 100% on basically everything in a desperate attempt to make it work, but i have also tried without them

you can see it better in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/levyks/pen/zYZBjZw

and even better in the fullscreen version of it:
https://codepen.io/levyks/full/zYZBjZw

EDIT: This is a gif on how i want it to behave, i was able to achieve it by adding this to the list-group css:

```css
height: calc(100vh - 238px);
```

[image: Example GIF]

but this is definitely not a good way to do it, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of `list-group` element.

Working example ([codepen](https://codepen.io/Kaper365/pen/gOmMKYO)):

```css
.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `calc()`:

```css
.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(0.50 * 100vh); //0.50 is percent of screen height
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but by doing that i will only get what i want in a really specific window height, using 50vh, it's perfect when the window height is 541px, anything bigger than that and i will be left with a blank space underneath, anything smaller and the scrollbar will appear again

Comment: Try to center your "box" vertically - this will remove blank space underneath. For smaller screens you can set media queries - I checked the code and the problem with scrollbar is caused by unsufficient plac on the screen. Try removing the padding of jumbtron or any other element, this will allow your box to stay within screen boundaries

Comment: I edited the post with a gif on how it should look, i was able to achieve it but in a really bad way I believe